# php extensions for iphone/ipad php port

Tags: php, ios

i'm installing my web service in my iPad through lighttpd/php from cydia but it seems that php comes without extensions.

To get my webserice working locally I need "php_mbstring" extensions.

Is there any site to download php extensions compatible with this version of php (5.2.8) in ios darwin?

Comment: You want `pear`. It can install PHP extensions.

Comment: If you really want to go this route, you should probably look into compiling PHP for iOS yourself.  If you're not willing to do that, your time is probably better spent picking a language that has better iOS support.

Comment: i need php_mbstring to start, not all extensions, but just in case, maybe i need more extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to compile PHP with the extensions for the ARM processor. Rather than installing the dev tools on the iPad, I'd cross compile from your normal box as it will be quicker. I'd be surprised if you could find PHP with them as a binary, as most servers don't run on ARM.

Comment: Hi, php, is ported to ios, it is a cydia package, but can not find the extensions.

Is there ani guide on how to build them?

thanks!

Comment: You normally compile php alongside the extensions.

Comment: right, that is wat i supposed, but i cant find the packager nor compile them. how may I compile them?, how to create the build environment?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like use a already built PHP 5.4.x Cydia package with following extensions:
fast-cgi, pdo_mysql, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd, pdo_sqlite, sqlite3, gd (gif, png, bmp, xbm, tiff, jpeg and FreeType2), mbstring, exif, dom, xml2, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xslt, json, pcre, phar, calendar, reflection, session, zlib, zip, bz2, mcrypt, openssl and soap,
please have a look at:
 
http://code.google.com/p/cydia-ios-lighttpd-php-mysql-web-stack/wiki/PHP
and/or
http://iOS-WebStack.tk

If you would like compile your own iOS PHP 5.4.x, please have a look at:
http://code.google.com/p/cydia-ios-lighttpd-php-mysql-web-stack/wiki/Main

There you will find a description to install/create an iOS SDK 3.0 Linux Cross Compiling System.